# Rapid on/off cycling of furnace

Tags: hvac, furnace, thermostat, gas, heat

My 50-year old wall furnace keeps cycling on and off as it gets near the set temperature. Can I fix this by changing to a new thermostat? It's a 2-conductor cable (no blower).

Comment: Could we get a Manufacturer and model number.

Comment: It's one of these classics: https://www.williamscomfortprod.com/product/monterey-home-furnaces/ We have the double model (both sides of the wall) with no blower. The thermostat is one of those old coiled spring contraptions.

Comment: I know I get kicked in the teeth about some of my comments about this, but have you ever thought about replacing a fifty year old furnace? I mean really what is the lifespan of a wall heater.

Comment: Hey RME, don't confuse us with the facts.  However, they still needs to deal with the rapid cycling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First purchase a new electronic thermostat, $20--$30  Install that in place of the existing stat. Tell us if things change.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of thinking along those lines.

Comment: This solved it for a remarkably simple and low-tech reason. The Honeywell digital thermostat I purchased works on 1 degree increments (the old one worked on a windey bimetalic strip). The 1 degree increment forces the furnace to stay on for a long enough period of time that it escapes the unstable equilibrium of the windey bimetalic strip and that translates to at least 1 hour intervals even on cold days. Problem solved.

Comment: @NetworkEffects If you'll take the [tour], you'll see that the proper way to let the world know that a particular answer solved your problem is to click the check-mark next to the answer. You can click the up vote button next to it, too, as a way of adding an additional "thanks".